# How to detect landmarks of a face including forehead?

Tags: python, algorithm, image, opencv, facial-landmark-alignment

[This](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/04/03/facial-landmarks-dlib-opencv-python/) tutorial teaches how to detect landmarks of a face.

[image]

Here, there are no landmarks for the forehead. What can I do so that the landmarks also detect the forehead?

Answer (score 0):

Forehead is not "re;iable" part of face, it's often being covered by hairs.. By the same  reason ears are not included too in that 68-points dlib model. So, you can either create your own model or use, for example, Mediapipe Mesh.